# How to power a Companion Computer using the Holybro Pixhawk 4 Power Module (PM07)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, power, mission-computer

As the title says, I would like to power a companion computer (Raspberry Pi 3B in my case) using the PM07 Power Distribution Module: [Power Module](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/power_module/holybro_pm07_pixhawk4_power_module.html)

The Raspberry Pi should be powered via USB cable.
Where would you attach the other end of the USB cable to the PM07?
What would be the best/safest way to go about this, without the need for another BEC if that is possible?

Comment: How did you end up solving the issue?

Comment: @Magnuss I got another 5V BEC and powered the PI over the pin header directly. The USB cable/connector caused significant voltage drops for me, leading to an unreliable power supply of the PI (still working but got frequent undervoltage warnings).